# Visualizing and planning mailing/permission groups

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to internally propose a plan concerning permission/mailing lists for office365 & SharePoint groups.

To do this, I thought the best way would be to create some kind of visualization of my proposal. I was not able to find anything via Google, there do not seem to exist many tools for this purpose.

Is there a tool to plan and visualize permission/mailing groups? (Instead of using excel)